# sbt: execute initialCommands silently

Tags: scala, sbt

Is it possible to execute `initialCommands` in the `console` task silently, i.e. as if

```
:silent

val $session = new foo.bar.Session()
import $session._
import $session.lib._

:silent
```

Putting these commands in `initialCommands` doesn't work, though, because `:<command>` commands apparently cannot be used in `initialCommands`:

```
Welcome to Scala 2.12.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_102).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> <console>:2: error: illegal start of definition
:silent
^
Interpreter encountered errors during initialization!

[error] (Thread-1) java.lang.InterruptedException

java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.put(SynchronousQueue.java:879)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.SplashLoop.run(InteractiveReader.scala:77)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as of 0.13.13, sbt runs the `initialCommands` early, while it's creating the interpreter, and before the console has a chance to bind the interpreter as `$intp`.

This is close:

```
$ sbt -Dscala.repl.maxprintstring=-1
[info] Set current project to sbt-test (in build file:/home/apm/tmp/sbt-test/)
> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala 2.12.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_111).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> ...

scala> Future(42)
...

scala> $intp.isettings.max
maxAutoprintCompletion   maxPrintString

scala> $intp.isettings.maxPrintString = 1000
$intp.isettings.maxPrintString: Int = 1000

scala> "hi"*1000
res0: String = hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi...

scala> Future(42)
res1: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = Future(Success(42))
```

It's a misfeature that setting `maxPrintString` to zero doesn't truncate everything, including the ellipsis, which is always residual.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of an sbt option to do that. In the lack of a better solution, you could hide all your setup in nice looking import as follows:

```
object console {
  object setup {
    val bar = foo.bar
    bar.init()
  }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

Note that this is equivalent to the code original code you wrote: it put a thing in scope called `bar`, which points to `foo.bar`. You can also use the same technique with types to group whatever imports you need into a single one. This is the mechanism used [Predef](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L1) to magically get `scala.collection.immutable.Set` (both the type and the value) in scope.

**Edit 2:**

> I guess your technique can't achieve that with a single import.

It still works. Suppose `Session` is defined as follows:

```
trait Session {
  val v
  def f
  lazy val l
  object o {}
  type T
}
```

then

```
val $session = new foo.bar.Session()
import $session._
```

becomes

```
object console {
  object setup {
    val $session = new foo.bar.Session()

    val v      = $session.v
    def f      = $session.f
    lazy val l = $session.l
    val o      = $session.o
    type T     = $session.T
  }
}
```

You can apply this transformation recursively for `lib._` and whatever other imports you have until you've built the exact same scope.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I also want to make some imports available for the rest of the REPL session.

Comment: Oh, I see. Anytime I try to simplify the example, there's a risk that I omit some important aspect. I edited my code snippet to better reflect my use case. I guess your technique can't achieve that with a single import.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. Not sure if I want to go down that path though, since `lib` has a lot of members.